# Initialize log4net without xml file

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net

I need to create a little wrapper for log4net package.

I also need to initialize the logger without using a xml config file (it's a requirement, there are already a lot of configuration files in this project).

I've written the `MyLogger` class, but when I run the program I don't see anything in the console.

I've tried to shrink the code in order to have a minimum example (I've removed my configuration file loading and some other thing).

At first I create the logger instance, I set the level to Trace, and then I add a `AnsiColorTerminalAppender`. Obviously there's something wrong or missing, but I can't understand what.

How can I fix my class in order to print the log message?

```
using log4net;

namespace MyProgram
{
  static class MyLogger
  {
    static ILog logger = null;

    public static void SetConfiguration()
    {
      logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyLogger));
      var l = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)logger.Logger;
      l.Level = log4net.Core.Level.Trace;
      AddConsoleAppender();
    }

    public static void Debug(string message)
    {
      logger.Debug(message);
    }

    public static void Info(string message)
    {
      logger.Info(message);
    }

    // Others here

    static private void AddConsoleAppender()
    {
      var appender = new log4net.Appender.AnsiColorTerminalAppender
      {
        Threshold = log4net.Core.Level.Info
      };
      var l = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)logger.Logger;
      log4net.Layout.PatternLayout layout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout
      {
        ConversionPattern = "%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n"
      };
      layout.ActivateOptions();
      appender.Name = "Console";
      appender.Layout = layout;
      appender.ActivateOptions();
      l.AddAppender(appender);
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      MyLogger.SetConfiguration();
      MyLogger.Info("Logger configuration loaded");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are adding appenders without using of `BasicConfigurator`, you should manually set `Configured` property of Logger repository to true. Just add following line to the bottom of `AddConsoleAppender()` method:

```
static private void AddConsoleAppender()
{
    // ...
    var l = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)logger.Logger;
    // ...
    l.Repository.Configured = true;
}
```